# Rank of a complex matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I was reading a text book, and encountered the following matrix:
$H = h[e_r(\Omega_{r1})$  $e_r(\Omega_{r2}]$.
Where, $e_{r}(\Omega_{rk})$ is a colomn vector with entries as $e^{-j2\pi k\Omega_{rk}}$. And it was written that the Matrix is a full rank matrix if $|e_r^*(\Omega_{r1}).e_r(\Omega_{r2})| \neq 1$.(* is the Hermitian operator)

How do we see the rank of a complex matrix? The expression appears to show that the given vectors are orthogonal. Are the matrices with non-orthogonal components always full rank?

Comment: The range of a matrix is also the span of its column vectors (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_and_column_spaces ). If the vectors are linearly independent the vectors span the whole space. Moreover orthogonality implies linear independence (but not vice versa of course).

Comment: @lcv Your statement "if the vectors are linearly independent the vectors span the whole space" only holds if the matrix is square; but it is not clear that this is the case here.

Comment: @BenGrossmann you're absolutely right of course. I was under the impression that matrices are square but that may not be the case. If that's not the case replace with "span a space of dimensions equal to the number of columns". This space is also the range of the matrix.